# Convert Pdf to Bitmap via code

Tags: vb.net, image, pdf, itext

I know there's tons of threads about this "out there" but all I can find is bitmap to pdf and how do add images to a PDF.

I have a PDF which I would like to convert to JPEG. I've tried to use the iTextSharp but I can only find info about making a pdf, not the other way araound. Any ideas or links to actual code?

Comment: You can try this wrapper... http://imagemagick.codeplex.com

Comment: Thanks! I've just made a quick look and tried to test it a bit, but does imagemagick needs to be installed on the client? I would prefer to just add a DLL to my project and don't force the user to install something else.

Comment: I don't believe so, just make sure your project references it.

Comment: Yes, that is a problem. A commercial library may be an option, but then i would like to buy it once and then be able to use/sell the product as i wish. Ghostscript can be bought for commercial usage as well.

Answer (score 2):

ImageMagick uses Ghostscript to handle PDFs so if this is your only task I'd recommend just using Ghostscript. There's a [managed wrapper here](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/) and you can get the [Ghostscript binaries from here](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html). They come in an installer but you can just extract them using 7-Zip. See [this discussion](https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/discussions/465418#PostContent_1184064) on what you need to deploy in your app. You might have to play around with 32-bit vs 64-bit. Also, on the Ghostscript download page please read the "Which license is right for me?" section.